# Убрать звуки в Android приложении

Tags: android, google-speech-recognition

[**Лишние звуки при получении результата в распознавании речи.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WyVI.jpg)

Я нашёл на Github Google API Voice непрерывное распознавание речи, но когда выводит результат или нет результата, приложение издаёт медийные звуки, подскажите как их убрать?

https://github.com/somil55/Android-Continuous-SpeechRecognition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы отключить звуки, можно использовать MediaPlayer :

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
```

и чтобы  выключить звук:

```
mp.setVolume(0,0);
```

так же можно использовать AudioManager:

```
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
             amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
```

Comment: Помогло: 
amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0,  AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI); Но это отключает звук, и в приложении нельзя использовать медия. Все ваши перечисленные варианты не помогли.

Comment: я же вам указал что можно использовать audiomanager чем вы и воспользовались, если у вас есть рабочий способ который решает вашу проблему то можете его опубликовать как ответ :)

Comment: он мне не подходит

Comment: так, у меня в ответе есть вариант отключать частично звуки в приложении, то есть грубо говоря вы можете выбрать что именно вам нужно оставить и остальное выключить, чем именно выражается тот факт что вам предложенные варианты не подходят?